# Firefox ignore my Cache-Control config and keep caching the webpage

Tags: firefox, caching

We have a Wordpress based website that use `<meta>` to allow front-end retrieve the user's login status. However, it seems like not working properly on Firefox. Firefox keep caching the webpage even we have `cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate` setup. I have tried few suggested solutions and none of them works on Firefox but works on Chrome and Safari. Here are the solutions I tried

```
# In the header of the page (Firefox just remove it from the page)
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" />
```

```
# From php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

```
# Apache config
Header always set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
```

You can visit [this page](https://academy.apnic.net/) on different browsers and see the response headers in the Web dev tool. My result from:
[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmPef.png) and my result from [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEnot.png).

Open to any suggestion, thanks much for help.

Answer (score 0):

After the investigation, it's due to the Cloudflare. Not sure why it only effect Firefox, but after DevOps team modify the config on Cloudflare, the issue is fixed.